# Solving equations with circular reference in R

Tags: r, equation-solving, linear-equation, rexcel

I have a set of following equations:

```
x = 11y
y = x-5
```

The above equations are easy to solve if I rearrange the variables and solve using matrices. However, I want to pass the above equation as it is and solve them. Can someone suggest a way?

Comment: I believe you are looking for package Ryacas.

Comment: Do you want an algebraic solution, in which case `Ryacas` , or do you want an iterative convergence solution, in which case  `optim` or `BB` or several other packages.